# i need to get a specific string using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, trim

i have a string like this

```
var x = "/projectx/index.php/Home/index"
```

i need a function to affect this sring to get an output value:

```
y = "/projectx/index.php/Home"
```

means to right trim and remove last word with separator `"/"`
also means the same function used in PHP

```
$y = rtrim($x, "/");
```

javascript doesn't have rtrim();

Comment: You can use regex for that, something like `"/projectx/index.php/Home/index".replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '')`

Comment: without regex: `x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf('/'))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750524/remove-last-directory-in-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105950/remove-last-folder-from-path-in-nodejs-with-trailing-and-no-trailng, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961777/removing-last-part-of-url-based-on, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886727/remove-last-element-from-url,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827287/javascript-string-trimming-url-and-file-path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161283/replace-only-last-path-part-in-url-not-parametres ...

Comment: [PHP's `rtrim` doesn't work like that.](https://ideone.com/QP5DIq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using JavaScript

```
function removeLastSegment(url) {
    return url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
   
var x = "/projectx/index.php/Home/index";
var y = removeLastSegment(x);

console.log(y);
// Output: /projectx/index.php/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

**In vanila javascript you can use a regex like below :**

```js
function extractBasePath(url) {
    const match = url.match(/^(\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/[^/]+)(\/|$)/);
    return match ? match[1] : null;
}

const url = "/projectx/index.php/Home/index";
const basePath = extractBasePath(url);
console.log(basePath)
```

**In PHP you can come up with something like :**

```
function extractBasePath($url) {
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    $path = $parsedUrl['path'];
    $basePath = dirname($path);
    $basePath = '/' . trim($basePath, '/');
    return $basePath;
}

$url = "/projectx/index.php/Home/index";
$basePath = extractBasePath($url);

echo $basePath; // Output: "/projectx/index.php/Home"
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a generic solution for removing the last segment of an URI. Your approach will always only extract the first three segments of an URI. It is not that generic.